# Find a formula for Taylor series of $\left(\frac{1}{1+z^2}\right)^n$

Tags: complex-analysis, taylor-expansion

So the way I think I should approach this is by getting a result for $n=1,2,3...$  and then examine them. I could easily get the Taylor series expansion for $n=1$, but then I don't really know how to proceed, because I can't always break down a power of a polynomial. And a power of a summation doesn't seem as a legit answer either.

Can anyone help? Thanks

Comment: Can you find a formula for the Taylor series of $$\left(\frac{1}{1-w}\right)^n\,?$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Expanding Daniel Fischer's comment, it is known that for any $x$ such that $|x|<1$:
$$\frac{1}{(1-x)^n}=\sum_{k\geq 0}\binom{n+k-1}{n-1}x^k,$$
hence (by replacing $x$ with $-x$):
$$\frac{1}{(1+x)^n}=\sum_{k\geq 0}\binom{n+k-1}{n-1}(-1)^k x^k$$
and (by replacing $x$ with $x^2$):
$$\frac{1}{(1+x^2)^n}=\sum_{k\geq 0}\binom{n+k-1}{n-1}(-1)^k x^{2k}.$$